# GoCD: where is cruise-config.xml Config XML located on disk?

Tags: go-cd

I locked myself out of my GoCD server, can't login and want to manually edit Config XML, which is supposed to be in `cruise-config.xml` file, as far as I can tell from the [documentation](https://docs.gocd.org/current/installation/configuring_server_details.html#artifact-repository-configuration).

Documentation never mentions the location of that file on the disk though. Can you help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the file is located on:

```
/etc/go/cruise-config.xml
```

If you are using a **Docker image**, so you need run "exec" to view/edit the file, ie:

```
docker exec go-server cat /etc/go/cruise-config.xml
```

Where **"go-server"** is the name of my container.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

According to a [similar Github issue](https://github.com/gocd/gocd/issues/734), `/etc/go/cruise-config.xml` is the right location on Linux.